# SQLite cannot overwrite default values using Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm playing around with SQLite and python. I am using sqlalchemy and have a table setup like so:

```
quizzes = Table("quizzes", metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key = True),
    Column("subject", String, default = "Math"),
    Column("description", String),
    Column("answer_a", String),
    Column("answer_b", String),
    Column("answer_c", String),
    Column("answer_d", String),
    Column("can_retry", Boolean, default = False)
)
```

Now I try to insert a row:

```
i = quizzes.insert()
i.execute({   "subject": "Biology",
    "description": "Where is the heart?",
    "answer_a": "In the head",
    "answer_b": "In the arm",
    "answer_c": "In the gut",
    "answer_d": "Dunno",
    "can_retry": True
})
```

However when I check the database after I notice that the `subject` is `Math` and `can_retry` is `0` even though I set them otherwise. What am I doing wrong? Why is it still using default values even though I am supplying new ones?

Comment: You haven't shown what you are doing with that "row". Please show the *exact* code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated